# Entity framework appending a decimal place to a field of type decimal(10,0)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF database first. In my database I have a field which I know will always be 10 digits long, so naturally I've opted for a `decimal(10,0)` type, when I insert values into the table I can insert any number up to 10 digits long, however when I insert an entity with EF6 it adds a 0 decimal and then throws a parameter out of range value. The type of the field in my C# code is `decimal`

[image]

Here is the entity immediately before calling `context.SaveChanges()`:

[image]

And a sanity check, here is the column in sql server:
[image]

**EDIT**:

Here is the EF mapping:

[image]

[Just reported it on codeplex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2415).

Comment: what is the datatype of NationalIdNo in the class ?

Comment: This looks like a bug (or, maybe you misconfigured EF and it thinks this is a decimal(10, 1)?). Please take the time to report it.

Comment: @YuliamChandra a C# `decimal`.

Comment: @usr What misconfig could it be? I haven't touched any of the config options, simply created a model from my database.

Comment: Then it could be an import bug. Look into the EDMX, search for that field name and make sure that the right type is specified in all places.

Comment: @usr I added the generated mapping

Answer (score 3):

The error sounds like a bug in EF, but if it is always an integer, wouldn't it make more sense to use an int instead of decimal? I am thinking both for logical and performance sake.

Comment: agree, didn't realize decimal takes more bytes than int.

Comment: I think a `bigint` would be better as `int` only goes up to 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in SqlClient - SqlDecimal code doesn't handle the precision correctly for some edge cases.

I believe the culprit is here:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDecimal.cs#416

However, given that this has been the behavior for a long time, it is very unlikely it will ever be fixed. I would recommend working around this by using bigint, like [user1648371](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24980227/209259) and  Andrew Morton have suggested.